# Suggested replication type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions, replication

I have 2 similar tables in different servers, data in certain columns can only be changed by server A while data in other columns can only be changed by server B.

However, I need these tables to always be consistent (1 minute schedule). Is this the kind of scenario that "Transactional replication with updatable subscriptions" solves?

Comment: Been a while, but sounds like merge replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx).

Comment: In this case, which server should I set as the Publisher? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: Obviously, I don't know all the specifics of your set up, but if both nodes are equally available, then the choice is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

YEs, updateable subscriptions allow for this, but that is a [deprecated feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151718.aspx):

> This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature.

The way going forward is [Peer-to-Peer Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx).

Comment: I'm reading this is a 2008 Enterprise feature, but thanks for letting me know the updatable subscriptions is deprecated !

Comment: From the link you provided, "We strongly recommend that write operations for each row be performed at only [one] node". I interpreted the OP as needing to update different columns of the same row at both nodes.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: true. Why I refrain from recommending Merge is because the underlying infrastructure for Merge is Triggers based and I found it not very scalable in real life. Transactional puts a much lighter load on the system, being log read based.